# How do I enable the num pad on microsoft ergonomic keyboard run by Mac?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Suddenly...the number pad does not work.   The numbers on the top do work.  This was sudden, overnight.    I have tried various pointer control, mouse keys, etc. as read online....I do not know how to 'unlock' mouse keys.   This was 'coincidently' ??....the day after I optioned a Mac update.   The mouse is wired.....

Comment: What exactly did you do to turn off mouse keys?  see https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250006675

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem too. The [Microsoft Bluetooth number pad](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-number-pad-ddc5eb8b-1368-fadf-dc5d-92e0bde0a745) can pair and switch with up to three Bluetooth devices.
(for example, my first device is a Windows PC and the second device is a MacBook)

I solved it using these steps:

1. Connect your Bluetooth number pad to your MacBook or Windows PC.
2. Switch to your Windows PC and run the [Mouse and Keyboard Center app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2).
3. In Windows, configure your MacBook device and change the **Backspace** default key to **Clear**.
4. Try to switch to the MacBook and launch the Calculator.

The problem is solved.